Erased comment?
Roughly an hour ago, I wrote a comment on this question. It wasn't offensive, I was merely pointing out the similarity with the arcsinh function and the obvious change of variable that it allows. An hour later, it has been removed. I know the rule is to avoid answering in a comment. This wasn't an answer, as far as I can tell. Is this fair game now?

All comments should be seen as ephemeral.  Comments which do not seek to clarify a question are likely to be deleted relatively quickly, and comments which do seek to clarify a question or answer will (hopefully) be deleted once the advice offered is incorporated into the post.  As I saw it, your comment gave a hint towards another possible solution.  Moreover, that hint had already been incorporated into another answer.  Hence there seemed to be no reason to keep the comment around any longer.

I see. Thanks for taking the time to answer. This is no longer the site I discovered with joy in october 2012. I have felt a tendency, for several years now, towards increasing aggressiveness and authoritarianism. Strong words, but it's how I feel, and this goes much farther than erasing a comment. I have tried to convince myself that I must adapt to the new rules. I have tried to pretend it doesn't matter, but it does. I'm no longer in a position to contribute serenely to this site, therefore it's better that I stop.

Well, I admit to being one who thinks hints as well as answers should not be posted in the comments in the first place--and thus deleted when they do appear. It--the hint-comments and answer-comments that is--tends to discourage people from posting a proper answer. There are also those of us here grumbling that MSE has become too much a homework-helping site you know, where banal questions are burying the good questions, and I think that the comment-hints and comment-answers have a lot to do with this. With that said Jean-Claude Arbaut, I do hope you stick around.

See also this meta question.  Personally, I think that adherence to the help center article referenced in one of the answers to the linked meta question seriously ignores reality.  It is a very widespread custom on MathSE to leave hint/comments that still leave the original poster with significant work to do.  The linked meta article discusses the issue of the will of the majority, which I regard as an unresolved issue, despite the metric of meta-article voting.

Re last comment, the linked meta question also discusses my take on effective guerrilla warfare.  In this instance, in my opinion, the only effective measure is to bring the linked meta question to the attention of other victims of the deleted comment custom, so as to eventually arouse a general feeling of anger to deleting such comments (help center article not withstanding).

By the way, I also upvoted your posted question.  Does that make me a hypocrite, for attempting to give weight to the metric of meta-article voting?
